# Mysql setting a record as deleted or archive

Tags: mysql, delete, record

Is there any way to omit some records in mysql select statement and not deleting them? We can easily add a column for example deleted and set it to 1 for deleted ones and keep them but the problem is that we have to put `where deleted = 1` in all queries. What is the best way to keep some records as an archive?

Answer (score 2):

You basically have two choices.  You could use a view to do the filtering though this has some performance issues on MySQL, or you could use a trigger to copy deleted rows into an archive table.  I suspect that on MySQL, the trigger solution will be much better (on other DB's the tradeoffs may go other ways.

Comment: Chris Travers: In View mode we will have 2 problems : first we have to make a view for each table and second is Inserts with duplicate key while you can not insert in to a view! and For Triggers , all your foreign keys will fail and again you have to make duplicate table for each table.

Comment: Yes, these are problems.  The other solution is just to add "and not deleted" to every where clause.  There is no free lunch.

Comment: I think mysql and other db engines must do sth about this!

Comment: You could probably repurpose Oracle's row-level security to do something like it....